# A question on a $Q$-set

Tags: general-topology

In a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864104002950), the author says that if there exists a $Q$-set, then there exists a "normal" [Mrowka space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/). But the details in the paper is few, and I cannot understand.

I want to know how to prove the space is normal. Could somebody help me?

> A subset $A$ of real line is called a $Q$-set if every subset of $A$ ia a $G_\delta$-set in $A$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where in this paper? $Q$ set does not appear in it.

Comment: $Q$-sets are usually combined in Michael line spaces (see the same topology blog for more info on those)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $Q$-set and Mrowka space appear between Proposition 1.2 and lemma 1.3.

Comment: These aren't proved in this paper, they refer to older papers (without the quotation to back it up), I believe. The existence might have been proved in the book Consequences of Martin's Axiom by Fremlin. There is some stuff on $Q$-sets in there and on Mrowka spaces. It's classical stuff, "folklore" as it were.

Comment: It's not in Fremlin's book. I checked. I found several papers mentioning normality of $\Psi$-spaces, none of them matching this result.

Comment: In the section on $Q$-sets in http://www.auburn.edu/~gruengf/7550/7550.14pfs.pdf one can get ideas, as think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for the link. It is very helpful for me!